# How to force a vector to be row vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

What is the most simple way to force any vector to be a row vector?

I wish to have some function that transforms column vector to a row vector, and leaves a row vector unchanged. For example:

```
A= [1 2 3];
RowIt(A)
```

will output a row vector:

```
1 2 3
```

and:

```
B= [1; 2; 3];
RowIt(B)
```

will output a row vector:

```
1 2 3
```

What is the most simple way to do it?

Comment: Transpose converts a row to a column and a column to a row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get any vector to be a row vector simply first force it to be a column vector, then transpose it:

```
A = rand(3,1);
B = A(:).'; % (:) forces it to unwrap along columns, .' transposes
```

A row vector gets unwrapped to a column vector and then transposed to a row vector again, and a column vector gets unwrapped to a column vector (thus doesn't change) and then gets transposed to a row vector.

Note that any N-dimensional matrix will be forced into a row vector this way due to column unwrapping:

```
A = rand(3,3,3,3);
B = A(:).'; % 81 element row vector
```

Answer (score 9):

Just reshape the matrix/verctor to a single row :

```
v = reshape(v,1, [])
```

It will also leave a vector of the right shape unchanged.

If you go to the [documentation on `reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), the `1` means 1 row, and the `[]` means as many columns as needed given the size of `v`.

The full function:

```
function v = RowIt(v)
    v = reshape(v,1,[]);
end
```

Comparing with @Adriaan answer

**`Reshape` version:**

```
v = rand(5000*5000, 1);
tic;
for i=1:100000
    b = reshape(v,1, []);
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.347047 seconds.
```

**`(:).'` version:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173784/5547936)

```
v = rand(5000*5000, 1);
tic
for i=1:100000
    b = v(:).';
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.082710 seconds
```

So @Adriaan's  solution is clearly faster, probably due to function call overload cost. You must know that no data is copied during this operation, except if you modify it  (MATLAB copy on modify), so it is really fast anyway.

The advantage is for reshape when you need to customize things, like:

```
a = rand(10, 10)
size(reshape(a, 2,[]))
```

> ans =
>
> ```
> 2    50
> ```

Comment: You may want to include what "1" and "[]" are doing here. Basically, reshape can convert your vector into an n-dimensional matrix based on the arguments provided. A row vector is of size 1-by-N, so beesleep tells reshape that the first dimension (The number of rows) is 1, and the second dimension is an empty set ("[ ]") which tells the reshape command to calculate what dimension works. In the end, reshape(v,1,[]) says "Form the elements of V into 1 row with however many columns are needed to store it all."

Comment: Your timing experiment, whilst interesting, doesn't give info on the question since the OP wants row/column to row, not matrix to row.

Comment: In term of speed, it is completely equivalent to the code with one column only. reshape, (:)  operations don't depend on the size of the array. It is just metadata changes. But for the sake of clarity, I changed the code to reflect you comment.

Comment: You should use `timeit` for timing. `tic`/`toc` is unreliable. And if you typed this directly in the command window then the JIT doesn’t apply and you’re not getting meaningful results at all. Always time within a function!

Comment: @CrisLuengo look at timeit code, It is using tic toc inside, (in my matlab version). From [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html), it is advised (as done here) to use tic toc outside a for loop for code faster that 0.1s or to use timeit. With timeit, warping the code in a function add also another call when measuring the time, which may change the relative result. Here, results are 10x longer with timeit than with tic toc without additionnal call. Anyway `(:).'` version is about 5 times faster, whatever the method of measure.

Comment: But it is about the use of JIT. For example, if I make a function M-file containing the `tic` and `toc` and the loop in between with Adriaan's answer, and call it, I see "Elapsed time is 0.013203 seconds". If I then copy-paste the contents of this function to the command line, I see "Elapsed time is 0.020839 seconds". And these times are repeatable within 10%. This means that the timing you get with `tic`/`toc` in the command line are not representative. This is why it is better to use `timeit`.

Comment: as explained in the matlab documentation, it is safe to use timeit it your call is longer than 0.1s. Internally timeit use tic and toc, but with repeated measures, outside or inside the loop to get a consistent result.

Comment: The problem is similar for any language, it is difficult to measure with precision small times. For those, you need to repeat the measurments. That what does timeit, and that's also what I'm doing using this for loop.

Comment: For the JIT remark, the commands were run in a script anyway. But focussing on absolute speed is not the deal here. You should rather look if the relative speeds (ratio between the two methods) are changing

Answer (score -4):

Transpose:

```
A= [1 2 3];
A.'
```

will output

```
1
2
3
```

You can also write:

```
transpose(A)
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html

Comment: This is close, but not quite what Michael was asking for. Michael wants a function that can be called on a vector regardless if it's a row or column vector, and always results in a row vector.

Comment: This would only be a good option if you e.g. wrap this in an `if` statement on its `size`, so as to make sure not to transpose a row vector to a column.